# Silverstripe Grouped List DataObjects - get variable from has_one in template

Tags: templates, variables, grouping, silverstripe, has-one

I'm struggling to get a variable in a template which contains a GroupedList of DataObjects that have a has_one relation to another DataObject.

Example:
I have the DataObject Team belongs to one region. When I get a GroupedList of the teams, grouped by the RegionID, I can't figure out how to access the Region.NAME in the template.

```
class Region extends DataObject {
private static $db = array (
    'NAME'    =>  'Varchar(128)',
    'INFO'    =>  'Varchar(128)',
    'PUBLIC'  =>  'Boolean'
);

public static $has_many = array(
    'Teams' => 'Team'
 );
}

class Team extends DataObject {
private static $db = array (
    'NAME'   => 'Varchar(255)',
    'LEAGUE' => 'Varchar(255)',
    'SORTNO' => 'Int'
);

 public static $has_one = array(
    'Region' => 'Region'
 );
}

class TeamRegionPage extends Page {
public function getRegionGroupedTeams(){
    return GroupedList::create(Team::get()->filter(array('PUBLIC' => 1))->sort('RegionID, SORTNO'));
}
}
```

TeamRegionPage.ss

```
<% loop $getRegionGroupedTeams.GroupedBy(RegionID) %>
<h2>Region name from has_one here: {$Region.NAME}</h2>

<% loop $Children %>
    $NAME<br>
<% end_loop %>
```

$Region.NAME is not working in the template and I tried a few other things. I have the feeling the solution is quite obvious but I can't see it and I'm stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround you can grab the first element of the current group's elements (aka `$Children`) and check the current region like this:

```
<% loop $getRegionGroupedTeams.GroupedBy(RegionID) %>
    <h2>Region name from has_one here: 
        <% with $Children.First %>
            $Region.NAME
        <% end_with %>
    </h2>

    <% loop $Children %>
        $NAME<br>
    <% end_loop %>
<% end_loop %>
```

Sidenote: please name your '$db` fields  more like the standard, 'CamelCase' instead of 'UPPERCASE'.

Comment: Thanks, that works great for my situation. If it gets more complex I might do manual looping like UncleCheese suggested. (The UPPER case field names are a legacy thing...)

Comment: I've shortened to `$Children.First.Region.NAME` now you can use it without  `<% with ..%>`

Answer (score 1):

That's not how GroupedList works. It only matches by the field value, not the relation itself. It seems to me you'd be better off looping Regions and creating an inner loop for teams, right?